# Do some basic arithmetic between a string and number in html with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I know there must be a simple solution to this that I can't figure out.

I have an array of objects that contain these two values:

```
team.seed: number,
team.placement: string
```

`team.placement` will either be a simple string like **7**, indicating a team made 7th place. It can also be something like `10T`, meaning they tied for `10th` place.

I'm creating a table that should print out all the differences between the initial seed and the final placement:

```
<tr *ngFor='let team of team_array'>
    <td>{{team.placement - team.seed}}</td>
</tr>
```

This works fine if placement does not have the trailing **T**, but prints a `NaN` value if it does. How can I handle placement so that I can get a numerical value in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse team.placement to number first,
try
`paresInt(team.placement)`

Comment: you can use also the `+`, like `{{+team.placement - team.seed}}`

Comment: parseInt(team.placement) works, but I'd like to keep the string value as well, as I use the full string elsewhere in my code.

Comment: I was hoping there is a way that I can call a function that runs for every <td> that is created. Something like <td value=getPlacementInt(team.placement)>{{value - team.seed}}</td>

Comment: How about create a custom Pipe? see [https://angular.io/guide/pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Comment: Or, in your component, declare a member parseInt = window.parseInt. Then you can just use {{ parseInt(team.placement) - team.seed }} in your template